# How could I know which core a process is running on?

Tags: c, linux, process, smp

I am currently working on a project about setting process to one core in linux environment. I use sched_setaffinity to do this job and I wonder whether there are some functions provided by linux to  get which core the process is running on. I use top command and find it could get this info using j   option. So i am sure there are some ways to get this info in user space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want `sched_getcpu()`.  If you are running an older version of glibc, you can read the 39th field of `/proc/[pid]/stat` for the appropriate pid -- see the `proc(5)` man page for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Glibc version is under 2.6 so it could not work

Comment: Ok.  Modified my answer to include a solution for pre-2.6 glibcs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline assembly (on a x86 arch) to achieve this:

```
mov eax, 1   ; cpuid functionality depends on the value of eax
cpuid        ; get cpu info
shr ebx, 24  ; ebx[31:24] is the cpu ID.
mov eax, ebx ; eax contains the cpu ID
```

you can read more about CPUID instruction here http://download.intel.com/design/processor/applnots/24161832.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, however my cpu is xeon 5560 and the os is  RHEL 5.4 64bit. Could CPUID still work as registers all changed names?